# How to use conditionals in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to generate info boxes that appear when you hover over an element. The thing is, each element could have 2 different values to display depending on which function was most recently run. I'll add some code in a bit, but first I'll explain what I'm trying. So I set a global flag `bySection = false` and at the end of each of my functions; `setBySection()` and `setByTotal()`, I set the flag to either `true` or `false`. So in my jQuery, I first check the boolean and want to generate my info boxes based off of this boolean. I can't figure out whether this is an issue with the way jQuery scripts things or if I have written my code wrong.

Here is my (general) code, please let me know if I need to add more detail:

```
var bySection = false;

function setBySection()
{
    //generate Sectional Data
    bySection = true;
}

function setByTotal()
{
    //generate Total Data
    bySection = false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    mergeSections();

    $("g").each(function () {
        var myid = $(this).attr('id');
        var maxAtt = 0;

        if (bySection == true)
        {
                    for (var i = 0; i < mapCode.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (mapCode[i] == myid)
                        {
                            var myCapacity = capacity[i];
                            var myAttendance = attendance[i];
                        }
                    }

                    var myPercent = myAttendance/myCapacity;
                    myPercent = myPercent.toFixed(2);
                    myPercent = myPercent * 100;

                    $(this).qtip({ // Grab some elements to apply the tooltip to
                        content: {
                            text: myAttendance + "/" + myCapacity + " = " + myPercent + "%",
                            title: {
                                text: 'Section ' + myid + ' Attendance/Capacity: ' ,
                                button: 'Close'
                            }},
                        position:
                        {
                            target: $(this),
                            at: 'top right',
                            my: 'bottom left',
                            adjust: {
                                mouse:false
                            }
                        },
                        show:{solo: true, ready: false, when: 'mouseover'},
                        hide: {when: 'blur', fixed: true}
                    });

        }
        else if (bySection == false)
        {
            //generate info box with Total Data
        }
```

The problem after running the code is that the info box always reports the Total Data, meaning bySection is always read as false by jQuery. I assume the problem is that `bySection` is initialized as `false` and jQuery only reads the value on `$(document).ready`.

How can I check the value of my boolean when I hover over the element rather than as soon as the page loads?

Comment: Please add your html as well. It sounds like you probably need to add an event handler for hover: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Where are you calling setBySection and setByTotal functions ?

Comment: Since you don't call setBySection() before, then the value stays false. Can you add a fiddle that we see the relevant code?

Comment: @RajeshP I have 2 buttons on my page that call the functions `onclick`

Comment: You're right, it's only setting the values when the page initially loads. If you're trying to change/check values dynamically (I think you want to achieve that when hovering over text). Check out [.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/). You need an event listener in order for this to work after the initial page load.

Comment: Can you please add a working example ?

Comment: Can I ask why you created 2 functions just to change the value of a variable? Why not set the value of the variable instead of calling the function?

Comment: @G.Hunt because the two functions pull completely different data

Comment: @hallleron I'm not quite sure how to set up a fiddle using external libraries and databases

Comment: @hallleron Just made an edit, added more detail to the code.

Comment: @RajeshP please take a look at the edit I made

Comment: Accepted answer is still up for grabs

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to check the value of the boolean on hover, the best way would be to use [jQuery's .hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) and set the callback function as the function used to generate the code. This must be still within the `$(document).ready` since you want it to only respond once the DOM of the page loads.

The code will look something like this-

```
$( "g" ).hover(
  function() {
    // functionality of code 
  }
);
```

Comment: Should I just embed `$("g").each(function () {...` within `$( "g" ).hover(
  function() {`?

Comment: if you want to run it on every g tag when you hover over any g tag then yes

Comment: Yes, in that case the code will execute any time after hover, and will thus take the current state of your boolean.

Comment: I would recommend creating a seperate class and using the `$('.className').hover` and run the `each` function inside it

Comment: @BanelingRush I want to run it only on the the g tag that I hover over. Would I just switch them in this case and embed `$("g").hover` inside of `$("g").each` ?

Comment: if you want it to run only on the g tag that you hover over ideally you want to use the  `$("g").hover` and then use `this` to access the specific element hovered over

Comment: And I don't want to create a separate class because I'm dealing with ~1000 lines of svg. I'd have to manually go in and change each one

Comment: In that case the above method is probably the best way to do it although it is still on the 'hacky' side

Comment: @BanelingRush Hmm. `.hover()` doesn't generate info boxes at all.

Comment: @BanelingRush Please check the edit I made for more perspective

Comment: the `.hover()` will only give you access to the handler for the hover you'll have to generate the info boxes inside the callback of the `.hover()` function like show in the above answer.